# Ansible - Executing task as non root user doesn't work

Tags: python, ansible, redhat, aix

I running into a problem when using Ansible to execute a task with 'Become' functionnality.
I'm using Ansible 2.9 on Red Hat OS and trying to execute my playbook to perform actions on AIX servers.

I log into AIX server with my personal account, which has no root privileges, and I can switch to user that has root privileges with:

```
sudo su - foo
```

I don't have to provide any password to switch to this user. In my Ansible playbook, I have this task which simply copies a file to the destination:

```
tasks:
    - name: Copy a file to targeted server
      become: yes
      become_user: foo
      copy:
        src: test.txt
        dest: /tmp/test_ok.txt
        owner: root
        group: system
        mode: u=rw,g=r,o=r
```

Ansible responds with an error :

```
fatal: [up0bd101]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "Missing sudo password"
}
```

In the Ansible host file, I used my personal credentials to perform the connection to the AIX server.

Do you know why Ansible requires the password (which I don't know) to be able to execute the task, when I don't need to provide the password when I'm currently logged on the AIX server and I want to switch to user 'foo' ?

I would appreciate any suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: Whether or not the Ansible user requires a password to run `sudo` depends on how `sudo` is configured on the remote host.

Comment: That is, the combination of `become: yes` and `become_user: foo` is just Ansible's way of saying "Run `sudo -u foo ...`".

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
There is no way to actually tell Ansible to change user, instead of using sudo -u ?

Comment: Update : I figured out that I wasn't able to perform become because of the settings of my user on the targetted server. It simply can't do sudo, but can switch to another user which is not possible with Ansible. Thanks chepner for helping me.

Comment: My last comment is not entirely accurate. You might be looking for the `ansible_become_method` variable.

Comment: I tried many options of `ansible_become_method` but it doesn't work, i suppose it's only because of the rights management of my targetted server. It works with an user which has sudo rights so I will proceed that way.

Comment: An alternative would be to use RBAC instead of sudo